# How to adjust the ticklabel for a polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted this Image

[image]

I'd like to prevent the 100 overlapping with the 20.

I know I can adjust the ticklabel with the command:

```
 ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', pad=15)
```

But the command only accepts `'y'`,`'x'`, and 'both' `for`axis`. How to adjust the ticklabel for the radius (the axis going from the center outward)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with `ax_set_rlabel_position()`.

```
ax.set_rticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100])
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. With the command ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5) i just rotate the position from the radius value. I wont to move the radius value to the inside. That its not overlapping anymore.

Comment: [Polar Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-demo-py) Take a look at this.